# How to select a value columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

```
ID Column1 column2

001 050 100
002 000 200
003 100 000
004 010 000
005 000 000
```

I want to display only values from column1 and column2.

Tried Query

```
Select id, Column1, Column2 where column1 <> '000' and column2 <> '000' 
-- Nothing data's displayed

Select id, Column1, Column2 where column1 <> '000' or column2 <> '000' 
-- data's are displayed below

ID column1 

    001 050 
    003 100 
    004 010
```

Expected Output

```
ID column1 column2

001 050 100
002     200
003 100 
004 010
```

How to make a query for the above condition, need Query Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correct, you want to select all rows where either Column1 or Column2 has a value different from `000` and for result rows change `000` to empty string.

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   CASE WHEN Column1 = '000' THEN '' ELSE Column1 END, 
   CASE WHEN Column2 = '000' THEN '' ELSE Column2 END
FROM Table
WHERE (Column1 != '000' AND Column2 != '000')
```